# What is the best way to handle a non-php dependency with composer

Tags: composer-php

I have a Symfony2 project which uses composer, and I'd like to use this css framework in it : https://github.com/jlong/sass-twitter-bootstrap

Of course, there is no such project on packagist, because this is not a php project. How should I handle this dependency to my project? With composer? If yes, how? Has the [package.json](https://github.com/jlong/sass-twitter-bootstrap/blob/master/package.json) file in this project anything to do with composer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, the best way is to not use composer but drop it in the public directory just like you would without composer.

There is a rather old feature ticket for supporting asset-type libraries in composer: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/524.

You can do what others in the feature ticket suggests and place it in your vendor dir from a zip distribution - but it will make your project structure rather messy.

The package.json in the project is a npm package info file (Node.js package manager).

Comment: The `require-extra` entry seems the way to go, I'll test that.